# Angular. Parent's button should navigate to one of the child's templates

Tags: html, angular, typescript

There is array of objects in parent's component:

```html
<div *ngFor="let sticker of stickers"
routerLink="sticker-details/{{sticker.id}}">
    <h3>{{sticker.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{sticker.content}}</p>
</div>
```

And also the button:

```html
<button (click)="add(sticker)">
</button>
```

When I click this button it only creates new empty object and adds it to array. Then when I click on this object it opens a child's component read template, and I have to click the edit button so it shows the edit template.
Here's the child component template:

```html
<div *ngIf="readTemp">
<button (click)="edit()"></button>
<button (click)="delete()"></button>
...
</div>

<div *ngIf="!readTemp">
<button (click)="cancel()"></button>
<button (click)="save()"></button>
...
</div>
```

And a parent's component method:

```js
add(sticker: Sticker): void {
            this.stickService.addSticker({sticker} as Sticker)
              .subscribe(sticker => {
                this.stickers.push(sticker);
    }
}
```

How can I make the add button to load the edit template and add a new object in array? 
I tried routing, it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the rest of your component code?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your existing code, this might work:

```
add(sticker: Sticker): void {
    this.stickService.addSticker({sticker} as Sticker)
      .subscribe(sticker => {
        this.stickers.push(sticker);
        this.readTemp = sticker;
     }
}
```

I am assuming your parent (where the `add()` method is) has the `readTemp` property which is then bound to child component's input.

You could stick that `this.readTemp = sticker` even sooner, before the call to `stickService`, if you don't need to wait for service to confirm adding it.